# bag_to_pcd Frame Id

Tags: ros, rosbag, pcl, bag-to-pcd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm processing a kinect point cloud with Electric + Ubuntu 11.10.  I've recorded a .bag file with the topics /tf & /camera/depth/points.  Using "rosbag play", rviz shows a beautiful point cloud.

I'm trying to convert the individual point clouds to pcd format so I can process them with PCL.  Initially, I got this [error](http://answers.ros.org/question/11978/how-to-find-the-frame-id-of-a-bag-file).  So, I followed the response to that question and ran:

```
rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link openni_camera 100
```

While I re-recorded the data in hopes of making bag_to_pcd happy.  Sadly, when I run

```
rosrun pcl_ros bag_to_pcd data6_2012_05_01.bag /camera/depth/points d6_expand/
```

I now get:

"Saving recorded sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 messages on topic /camera/depth/points to d6_expand/

[ERROR] [1335911911.695897268]: Frame id /openni_rgb_optical_frame does not exist! Frames (3): Frame /openni_camera exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /base_link exists with parent NO_PARENT.

Segmentation fault"

How can I make bag_to_pcd happy?  Should I attempt to change the bag_to_pcd code? Specifically,

```
pcl_ros::transformPointCloud ("/base_link", *cloud, cloud_t, tf_listener);
```

& if I should change it what should it be?  Would

```
pcl_ros::transformPointCloud ("/tf", *cloud, cloud_t, tf_listener);
```

work?  I'm a  new to ROS so I don't fully understand what is going on yet.  This seems to be a reoccurring issue on both the ROS questions and PCL users lists so I'd love to get fixed.

Thanks for you help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33072/bag_to_pcd-frame-id/) by [dtj](https://answers.ros.org/users/2288/dtj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-05-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I actually think that bag_to_pcd is broken and I'm not sure if it is actually still maintained. See [this](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5257) ticket. The fact that it requires a TF tree at all makes it really hard to use in many environments. What I did to be able to transform any point cloud is to change it to not do any TF transforms at all, i.e. I got rid of the call to transformPointCloud replaced all occurrences of cloud_t by cloud in the rest of the code. Note that this might break some use cases that actually require transformation of the point cloud to a common frame.

Replacing the target frame "base_link" with "tf" will probably not work. Rather, you could change it to openni_camera.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dtj](https://answers.ros.org/users/2288/dtj/) on 2012-05-02**:
I didn't actually do this (what was below worked), but it's a great idea, would totally work, & this should  be incorporated into ros.  Is there a way I can +1 this somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

just out of curiosity, what happens, if you run
"rosbag play yourbag.play"
in one console, and in the other console
"rosrun pcl_ros pointcloud_to_pcd input:=/camera/depth/points"

---

Originally posted by [Moataz Elmasry](https://answers.ros.org/users/116/moataz-elmasry/) with karma: 126 on 2012-05-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dtj](https://answers.ros.org/users/2288/dtj/) on 2012-05-02**:
This works, thank you!